# Ubuntu 12.04 is soundless! (only ready and startup :( )

Tags: 12.04, sound, windows, compaq

Windows. is the operating system that most popular from microsoft which has many sound effect, such an error, exclamation, start, off, etc.
Now you have to help me to "Re-enable" these sound bellow:
-log off,
-shutdown (already apply since 4.04 but discontinued since 8.04).

that's it! @Compaq510 @Ubuntu12.04
answer it with detail such editing .sh, or else as you can!
other sound in 12.04 such critical stop, warning, etc. is just applied. some other hidden not. so Hidden sound is Bonus Mission!
Good luck :D

Comment: Can you make it clearer, please? I really dont understand the reference to Compaq510 and Ubuntu 12.04, but may be thats just me.

Answer (score 1):

One problem I've noticed with the sound is that there is a separate volume slider for alerts, and it is often minimized.  This causes many sound effects to be muted.

Open the Sound Settings dialog, which you can get to from "System Settings", "sound", and check the tab for "Sound Efficts"; right at the top is a slider for "Alert volume:".  Make sure this slider is high enough (to the right) to be heard, and, of course, does not have the "Mute" checkbox checked.

If this isn't it, perhaps there's another setting that will help, but it's unclear from your question exactly what problem you're having.

Comment: For some reason 12.04 has the alert sounds muted by default, un-checking the box beside the alert volume slider will allow them to be heard and Marty says.  However I'm not aware that there are any "log off" or "shutdown" sounds that are included in Ubuntu by default only the sound when the login-screen starts and when there is a question, i.e. "do you want to close all tabs"(in browser)

Comment: no! i,ve already set it that since first time.

Comment: Now I need log off sound, and shutdown sound!

Comment: My opinion is that the Unix philosophy (inherited by Linux, somewhat) was that the system keeps quiet when everything is OK; originally, it was just with output to the terminal, but the philosophy is that the users are knowledgeable; a logon sound may be helpful to get your attention that it's ready, buy when you logoff or shutdown, there's really no more you can do, so there's no reason to get your attention, and many would be annoyed by the sound.

Comment: @JoelRobert Welcome to AskUbuntu!  If you found this answer helpful, please click on the gray tick-mark beside the question to accept it.